# Traveling with cash from US to UK

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration

How much U.S. currency am I allowed to carry from the U.S. to the UK?  Also how many British Pounds, am I allowed to carry with me?

Comment: As much as you want, but if the total value of your cash is over USD 10,000 then you must report it to US authorities. There is a similar requirement in the UK, but I don't know what the limit is.

Comment: Currency of any denomination and in aggregate amounting to more than EUR 10k must be declared when entering the UK. It is an EU regulation. It includes banker's drafts and travellers cheques also.

Answer (score 8):

Collating answers from comments:

**Leaving the US:** You can carry as much currency as you want, but if the *total value* of your cash is over USD 10,000 then you must report it to US authorities.

Since departing travelers do not go through systematic customs screening, it is your own responsibility to seek out the right authorities to declare the currency to at the airport. If in doubt, ask at the check-in desk where to find Customs.

**Entering the UK:** You can carry as much as you want, but currency of any denomination and in aggregate amounting to more than EUR 10,000 must be declared when entering the UK. It is an EU regulation. It includes banker's drafts and travellers cheques also.

Choose the "goods to declare" lane when exiting the baggage claim hall.

---

In both countries authorities have surprisingly broad powers to seize large amounts of cash that they think are proceeds of crime -- so it you're even close to the 10K declaration limit you should travel with the best documentation for where the money comes from and what you're going to use it for that you can lay your hand on.

Comment: When entering the UK, you must declare in Euro or in UK Pounds ?

Comment: @Max: Never tried myself, but I suppose you declare which amounts of which currencies you have with you.

Answer (score -3):

There is **no limit** on the amount of currency or equivalents you can carry between the US and the UK.

Related, if the total is over 10,000 local, you just have to declare it to local Customs in and out.

Comment: This advice is incorrect for the United Kingdom, as noted in the comments and the other answer.

Comment: @phoog I used local to avoid the complication of the three currencies involved.  Its also likely the UK rule will change soon.  I would modify it but since it's already been downvoted, I'll just leave it.

Comment: Perhaps if you fix the answer, the downvoter will remove the downvote (I can't say for sure since I did not vote).  The UK rule is unlikely to change for at least two years, which doesn't look particularly "soon" at the moment.

Comment: @phoog Maybe, but unlikely.  Since I already got dinged, I'll leave it.